# MacBook Air starts to heat up when turns on

Tags: macos

My MacBook air begins to heat up everytime I its tur on, after few minutes the fan starts to become noisy, what can I do to solve this problem?

This is the screenshot of my activity monitor and console
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have an MBA that does the same thing when I am in a very hot environment; this is normal behavior.  To better answer you question, you need to provide details like what's the ambient temperature, when do the symptoms occur - all the time or just certain times and especially,  what version of macOS you are running.

Comment: While I would still try the options in my answer, @Allan does have an excellent point. You can refer to the [Intel Mac Temperature Database](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) to get a sense of the various temperatures that Macs can run at. For MBAs they're typically in the range of 40º C (104º F) to 100º C (219º F). However, if you have a faulty sensor, your MBA could be triggering the fans because the system _thinks_ it's overheating when it's not. That's why testing the hardware is a good troubleshooting step if resetting the SMC doesn't change things.

Comment: Well, it happens everytime I turns on my MBA and my average temperature is around 27° Celcius

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is reset the System Management Controller.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your MacBook Air
2. Unplug its power cable
3. For 10 seconds, press and hold at the same time the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> keys (on the **left** side of the **built-in** keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. After 10 seconds let go of all keys and the power button
5. Plug in the power cable
6. Switch your MacBook Air on with the power button

Once you've done this, test to see if the problem is still present. If it is, you can boot into Safe Mode to see if the issue still persists.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your MacBook Air into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook Air
2. Restart your MacBook Air
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does it heat up, are the fans noisy, etc)
6. To exit Safe Mode just restart your Mac as normal

If the issue doesn't occur while in Safe Mode, boot your MBA normally to see if it returns.

On the other hand, if the issue still occurs while in Safe Mode, I strongly suggest you test your hardware. Depending on the exact model of MacBook Air, you will either use Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics.

If your MacBook Air was introduced:

- **before June 2013**, use **Apple Hardware Test**
- **after June 2013**, use **Apple Diagnostics**

Choose the appropriate process below.

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

If your MBA uses Apple Hardware Test, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Air
2. Restart your MacBook Air
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start.
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow.
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** that the extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

If your MBA uses Apple Diagnostics, follow the steps:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook Air
2. Restart your MacBook Air
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Regardless, take a note of what happens and let me know how you went.

**[UPDATE]**

Now that we've established the issue doesn't occur while you're booted into Safe Mode, we know that your hardware is okay. This means the problem is essentially software related.

I would now check what you have listed in your Login Items. To do this:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Make sure your User Account is selected at top left
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Make a note (or take a screenshot) of what items you have listed there
5. Now remove each of the items by clicking on their name (so they're highlighted) and then clicking on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button
6. Once all items are removed, exit System Preferences
7. Restart your Mac
8. Test to see if the problem still persists
9. If the problem persists, stop here and let me know. If the problem has gone away, continue below
10. Repeat Steps 1 to 3
11. Click on the plus <kbd>+</kbd> button to add **one** of the items back
12. Exit System Preferences
13. Restart your Mac

If the problem returns, repeat Steps 1 to 3 and then remove the item again. If the problem didn't return, start again at Step 10. Continue this process until you identify the item(s) that cause the problem.

Comment: Nothing happen in the safe mode but after I restart my MBA the issue came back. Tried Apple Diagnostics and it said there is no issue found

Comment: Well, that's a good thing! :) If it doesn't happen in Safe Mode that means your hardware is okay and that the problem is essentially software related. I've updated my answer with what you now need to do.

Comment: Removed all of them but the problem still returns :(